# WSO2 API Manager - Generating usage reports

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

We are using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 along with WSO2 DAS 2.0.0 standalone versions

Requirement : Generate API usage report for a user for a particular time period

How do we achieve this? 
we could see following data in publisher statistics. API usage graph for users(user wise split available,no option to filter based on time period) and API usage graph which covers all users(can filter based on time period but no user wise split available). 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can get API Usage graph based on a particular user as mentioned in [1] and the time period either Day/Week/Month only. In the current implementation time period for hourly can not be generated.

When you get the API usage graph for all users it filters for a particular time specified for all the users(publishers) under the same tenant.

[1] http://rukspot.com/wso2_apim_statistics_model.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm using API Manager 2.0.0 standalone version. The API Usage graph in publisher statistics doesn't have user-wise split available. Is there any configuration i'm missing?